# Community Sqlite NOT Handling Dates & DateTimes Correctly

Tags: sqlite, mvvmcross

**It seems that this new version is not handling dates correctly**. Please see the below observations:

1) When using the below:

```
_conn.Create<MyTable>();
```

And I have a **DateTime** field in **MyTable** class, then, it's creating it as **BIGINT** column inside the SQLite DB.

2) If I change the **BIGINT** column to a **datetime**-to match the **DateTime** definition in **MyTable** class-any existing rows are read back as **01/01/0001**!

3) If I try to save a date value into that datetime field, say, set it to **DateTime.Today** it's saving it as **30-12-1899**. And it doesn't matter what value you try to save. It's always saved as **30-12-1899**.

**NOTE:** I'm using MVVMCross on Android.

T.I.A.

Comment: Could you please share the "good" connection string you have make the input date stored as it was passed? Thanks much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a long story in the `SQLite-net` code about how DateTime should be stored.

You can read more about this and find plenty of opinions and links on https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/213

As a result of this discussion, the new SQLite port uses `StoreDateTimeAsTicks` as it's default setting.

Given the weight of opinions from people on the above github issues thread, I'd recommend using the `StoreDateTimeAsTicks` setting. If there are bugs (as you suggest in 3) then I'd recommend chasing this through with the SQLite-net community - including details about the platform and version you are using.

If you want to change this setting, then you can pass in:

```
 options.StoreDateTimeAsTicks = false
```

to the SQLite factory.

For more info on options see: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-SQLite/blob/master/Sqlite/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Community.Plugins.Sqlite/BaseClasses.cs#L27

Comment: Thanks Stuart for your response. So, if I choose to keep the StoreDateTimeAsTicks as it is, what data type should my "date" or "datetime" property be on my "MyTable" C# class and what SQLite datatype should the table column be? Thanks again for the info. I'll check it out.

Comment: @Pap You've probably already figured this out by now but in-case anyone else comes looking then just have the property on your class as a DateTime and the column in the database should be a bigint. One thing to be aware of that we ran into is that the int stored is ticks since DateTime.MinValue so if you want to use strftime() to get a date out with sql you need to do some adjustment as it'll be expecting unix epoch.

Comment: @Tom, I actually figured out that setting StoreDateTimeAsTicks=false does the trick. My C# property remains DateTime and the mapped SQLite column also remains DateTime. Personally, I don't like the idea of having a DateTime Property mapped to a BIGINT column. Thanks anyway though.